# jQuery photo gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have implemented a photo album which present a series of image thumbnails (of 200px) in a Web page but I also want to allow the user to display full-size views of the pictures by clicking on the thumbnail. The full-size view should be displayed in the same page by hiding the thumbnail index. So once the user closes the full size image, the thumbnail index is displayed again. I have the following code that reads all the pictures from a JSON file and append them to the div#images and apply CSS to them with img {height:200px, width:200px}.

```
var imageList;
$.getJSON('images.json', function(data) {
    imageList = data;
    for (var i = 0; i < imageList.length; i++) {
        $('<img>').attr({src: imageList[i].img_src, 
                    title: imageList[i].title}).appendTo('#images');    
    }
});
```

I am new in jQuery and want to do the task above so any answer on how to do it would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you have a look at this?http://tympanus.net/Development/MultiMediaGallery/

Comment: Did you want to implement this using custom code, or did you want a library that does this already?

Comment: @Tariqulazam nice implementation but could you be more specific which function does this in the photo gallery to get an idea?

Comment: @kokosg - Its a jquery plugin and all the functionality is wrapped within the plugin itself. You just have to initialize it with the images. You can have a look at the source code to see how it works. Let me know if you need any working sample.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this:

```
Replace <img> as img.
```

change this,

```
$('<img>').attr({src: imageList[i].img_src, 
                    title: imageList[i].title}).appendTo('#images');
```

use this,

```
$('img').attr({src: imageList[i].img_src, 
                title: imageList[i].title}).appendTo('#images');
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at what I'm doing here and reverse engineer it to suit your needs: http://oregonadventuretours.com/

Notice how I'm just showing and hiding a div with more content in it, in your case, it would be the larger photo.